# Merge 2 lists of 2 different types (alternatives)

Tags: linq, list, join, merge

I have 2 generic Lists `List<type1> L1` , `List<type2> L2` in C# V4

My Problem: type1 has an attribute called "key1" and type2 has an attribute called "key2", I want to merge L1 and L2 into a unique list on key1 = key2.

I need to merge these with a dynamic way, because I don't know the attributes of both classes, I just know that the first attribute of each type is the primary key.

Comment: What do you mean by 'first attribute'?

Comment: I have 2 lists:
list1<type1>
list2<type2>

each class have many attributes, so the First Attribute is the primary key of each object in list

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = (from type1 in list1
           join type2 in list2 on type1.Id equals type2.Id
           select new {type1, type2}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, What about if I don't know the name of the First attribute of each class?

Answer (score 0):

By saying 'attributes', I assume you are referencing either properties or fields.
Please don't use 'attributes', as this is confusing and means entirely different thing:

```
[Attribute]
class type1
{
  public int Field;

  public int Property { get; set; }
}
```

So, you have type1 and type2, and want to join them in one list based on first field or property in class. If you could know name of property, simplest implementation would be to use dynamics (assuming Prop1 and Prop2 property names):

```
var foo = 
(from type1 in list1
 join type2 in list2 on ((dynamic)type1).Prop1 equals ((dynamic)type2).Prop2
 select new {type1, type2}).ToList();
```

Since this is not the case, and we want to select 'first' field OR property in class, our only way is to use reflection. If you know that you have only properties in your class (or only fields) - you can use simple implementation:

```
var t1 = typeof(type1);
var t2 = typeof(type2);

//replace with .GetFields() if neccessary
var p1 = t1.GetProperties()[0]; // find first declared property of type1
var p2 = t2.GetProperties()[0]; // find first declared property of type2

var foo = (from obj1 in list1
       join obj2 in list2 on p1.GetValue(obj1,null) equals p2.GetValue(obj2,null)
       select new {obj1, obj2}).ToList();
```

If fields and properties are intermixed in your classes, you could list all members using **FindMembers(MemberTypes.Field|MemberTypes.Property...)**, but this approach has a problem - fields are always relocated to the beginning of class, and although fields order seem to be preserved, in following case F1 will always be returned as a first member of class (GetFields() will return F1,F2, and GetProperties - P1,this[]):

```
class A
{
  public int P1 { get;set;}
  public int F1;
  public int this[int x] { get{return x;} set {} }
  public int F2;
}
```

Also, there are other problems with this approach:

- what if your first property is an indexer? (int this[..] in example above)
- what if object returned by your first field/property do not implement overload for Equals?
- what if your first property do not implement getter (rare, but possible)? etc

And generally, this design (when you don't know field/property names, and rely on their relative location in a class) is considered bad. Citing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2w5ey1e.aspx):
...*The GetMembers method does not return members in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which members are returned, because that order varies.*